# Loading external html using jquery.load() function gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I had a previous post related to this problem but I guess I was not clear enough or some other reason, I did not get a solution. 
[Old post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937593/jquery-load-function-page-loading-issue)

I now have minimized the whole html to just demonstrate the problem and uploaded the html. 
[Here the link to the loaded HTML](http://writetonsharma.github.io/EmbedHtmlFailTest/main.html)

There are two html files - main.html and sample.html. Main.html loads sample.html using jQuery.load(). There is a JavaScript inside the sample.html which query the width of a div and visibility of a div. Both queries gives wrong results. You can look at the debug console of the browser for the results returned. I have tried FF, IE and chrome and all gives the consistent wrong values. I guess I am not doing something correctly. What could be wrong here ?

Comment: are you executing sampleHtmlFn after the whole page is loaded?

Comment: yes, I call sampleHtmlFn in the callback of jquery.load() function which is expected to be called after sample.html is loaded. If I am correct ?

Comment: just as test: does the situation change if you code the css inline?

Comment: If the CSS is internal or inline, problem do not reproduce. But my CSS is external.

Comment: The problem seems that sampleHtmlFn execute when HTML is loaded, but css is not.

Comment: The function must be executed with document.ready

Comment: Try applying this: $('#divid').load("sample.html",function(){ $('#divid').trigger('create'); });

Comment: Or this: $('#divid').load("sample.html",function(){ $('#divid').trigger('pagecreate'); });

Comment: I didn't get what you suggesting. Where will I call the function ? Can you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: I have limited knowledge of JavaScript. I tried this, not sure this is what you meant.
$('#divid').load("sample.html", function(){
 $('#divid').trigger('pagecreate',function(){
  sampleHtmlFn();
 });
});
Function sampleHtmlFn() was not called.

Comment: I mean: $('#divid').load("sample.html", function(){  $('#divid').trigger('pagecreate'); sampleHtmlFn(); });

Comment: Getting same output, 872 and visible. Here is the final code as you suggested:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#divid').load("sample.html", function(){
  $('#divid').trigger('pagecreate');sampleHtmlFn();
 });
});